# Update JSON file parameters daily using Powershell script

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I have a JSON file that contains a query I am using to pull audit history data from Oracle. I need to be able to automate changing the `fromDate` and `toDate` parameters daily. I was thinking to create a powershell script and use: `Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"` as a variable, but not sure this is the best approach? My JSON file (Oracle.json) looks like this:

```
{
  "fromDate": "2019-04-18",
  "toDate": "2019-04-18",
  "product": "OPSS",
  "eventType": "RoleMembershipAdd"
}
```

I am then using curl to make the POST request and output the data to flat file:

```
curl.exe -i --user username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@C:\Oracle.json" hxxps://someurl.com/fscmRestApi/fndAuditRESTService/audittrail/getaudithistory >> C:\Oracle.txt
```

What would be the best way to make the dates dynamic so I can have the script run daily and pull from that day without having to change the dates manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a here string and directly insert the date:

```
$Json = @"
{
  "fromDate": "$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd")",
  "toDate": "$(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd")",
  "product": "OPSS",
  "eventType": "RoleMembershipAdd"
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

---

```
> $Json
"fromDate":"2019-04-23","toDate":"2019-04-23","product":"OPSS","eventType":"RoleMembershipAdd"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Took me a little bit to figure out how to pass it through curl. I ended up using: -d"@-". So it looks like the following: curl.exe -i --user username:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@-" hxxps://someurl.com/fscmRestApi/fndAuditRESTService/audittrail/getaudithistory >> C:\Oracle.txt. For some reason it wouldn't take it with: -d $Json. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, hint for a new user: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)